# NextJS 14 internationalization server and client side?

Tags: next.js, internationalization, react-i18next, app-router

Now in NextJS 13 and above we have the App router, which makes internationalization a bit different than before. I've read multiple guides and how-to's, but the thing that is still not clear to me is if we need different ways of handeling translations on server side / server component and client side.

For example I checked out react-i18next, but I see you've to define a function to handle server components but also an additional function for client components, see https://i18nexus.com/tutorials/nextjs/react-i18next or https://locize.com/blog/next-app-dir-i18n/

I'm wondering if this is just the way how it should be? Or is this just as complicated as I think it is. Once you have to switch a component from server to client, you have to rewrite the translation part in that component as well..

TLDR: is it really necessary to use two different functions/ways to handle translations in nextjs app router? One for server side, one for client side.